# Hibernate composite key not working

Tags: java, database, hibernate

Here is the code I am using:

Database:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `btech_faculty_assigned` (
      `subject_id` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
      `year` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
      `section` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
      `branch` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
      `semister` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
      `FID` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
      `islab` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`subject_id`,`year`,`section`,`branch`,`semister`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

hbm file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.att_marks.students.BtechFacultyAssigned" table="btech_faculty_assigned">
<composite-id>
<key-property name="subjectID" column="subject_id"/>
<key-property name="year" column="year"/>
<key-property name="section" column="section"/>
<key-property name="branch" column="branch"/>
<key-property name="semister" column="semister"/>
</composite-id>

<property name="FID" column="FID"></property>
<property name="islab" column="islab"></property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

POJO file:

```
package com.att_marks.students;

public class BtechFacultyAssigned {
    private String subjectID;
    public String getSubjectID() {
        return subjectID;
    }
    public void setSubjectID(String subjectID) {
        this.subjectID = subjectID;
    }
    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
    public String getSeciton() {
        return section;
    }
    public void setSeciton(String section) {
        this.section = section;
    }
    public String getFID() {
        return FID;
    }
    public void setFID(String fID) {
        FID = fID;
    }
    public String getSemister() {
        return semister;
    }
    public void setSemister(String semister) {
        this.semister = semister;
    }
    public String getBranch() {
        return branch;
    }
    public void setBranch(String branch) {
        this.branch = branch;
    }
    public String getIslab() {
        return islab;
    }
    public void setIslab(String islab) {
        this.islab = islab;
    }
    private String year;
    private String section;
    private String FID;
    private String semister;
    private String branch;
    private String islab;

}
```

The entire project works fine as long as this hbm file is not included in the configuration file. The moment this file is included in the configuration file, the `sessionFactory.createQuery(query)` file throws null pointer exception.

Comment: Or any logfile showing a problem that occures when hibernate starts / parse the configruation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Hibernate doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-compositeid) said:

> A table with a composite key can be
>   mapped with multiple properties of the
>   class as identifier properties. The
>     element accepts
>     property mappings and
>    mappings as child
>   elements.
>
> **The persistent class must override
>   equals()  and hashCode() to implement
>   composite identifier equality. It must
>   also implement Serializable.**

Even if this is maybe not the cause of your problem (but the behavior looks like), you have to follow this requirements and add `equals`, `hashcode` and `serilizable`.